Vuetify 2 v-menu left sided | (Vuetivy 3 substitute)
I'm trying to make a Vue&Vuetify application, and I've been searching a way to make my Menu dropdown be Left sided
Header Dropdown center aligned
In vuetify 3.0 we may use 'Location' but this attribute was not implemented in V2
APIs below
https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/#links
Basicaly vue structure is a header that has a list of elements, and one of these elements is my own component, that will open a list
<v-menu 
      offset-y
    >
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn
          block
          color="primary"
          dark
          large
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on"
          :class=projecClassProps
          class="font-weight-bold"
        >
          Projects
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <v-list color="primary">
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(item, index) in items"
          :key="index"
          class="justify-center"
        > {...}

Can someone help me getting a way to do this component be on left side?
I'm planing on using "!this.$vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp" in order to make it responsive, as the left sided behavior will only happen in mobile application
I've already tried 'left' and 'offset-x' attributes from Vuetify 2
When using 'left', the menu slightly moved to the direction

Props left and offset-x together achieve the effect of left aligning the menu, and can work with offset-y to additionally bottom align.
<v-menu 
  left 
  offset-x
  offset-y
>

codepen example

Thank you yoduh
Worked here, really though I've tried this one
<>.<>'
Thank you so much for the force
